# OS X LoginHook - nc exits prematurely for no apparent reason

Tags: bash, macos, netcat, login-script

I'm trying to use [loginhook](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2420) to download large amounts of data and I've been having problems which I've nailed down to nc exiting prematurely for no apparent reason. This is a simplified test script:

`#!/bin/bash
exec > /tmp/lhook.out.txt 2> /tmp/lhook.err.txt
nc -v server 4444 > /tmp/nc-test
echo "Exit value: $?"`

On the server, when I run a simple nc listener like `echo "Hello world. | nc -l 4444`, the transfer works correctly. But when I want to transfer a larger file, like `nc -l 4444 < /path/to/some/large.file`, the client transfers only a small part (sometimes 2kiB, sometimes ~250 kiB). The exit value reported is 0.

Oh, and of course - the same script executed in a Terminal.app inside a user session works fine.

Can someone help with debugging, explain what is going on, or provide a solution?

**EDIT**:
I've had `dtruss` snoop on netcat's syscalls, and this is what I got:

```
  157/0x4c6:  write(0x1, "j,\350\037\376\377\377\203\304$f\211F\016\350&f\004\0", 0x400)                 = 1024 0
  157/0x4c6:  select(0x5, 0x7FFF53A87B40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)                 = 1 0
  157/0x4c6:  read(0x4, "\001u\374)u\f\215\f6\203\304\020\003\331\001\b\353\035\017\267\003\213\027P\213\317\377R\004\271\377\377\0", 0x400)    
         = 1024 0
  157/0x4c6:  write(0x1, "\001u\374)u\f\215\f6\203\304\020\003\331\001\b\353\035\017\267\003\213\027P\213\317\377R\004\271\377\377\0", 0x400)   
         = 1024 0
  157/0x4c6:  select(0x5, 0x7FFF53A87B40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)                 = 1 0
  157/0x4c6:  read(0x4, "\0", 0x400)             = 0 0
  157/0x4c6:  shutdown(0x4, 0x0, 0x0)            = -1 Err#57
  157/0x4c6:  close(0x4)                 = 0 0
  157/0x4c6:  close(0x3)                 = 0 0
  157/0x4c6:  close(0x3)                 = -1 Err#9
```

I'm guessing that for some reason, the kernel is giving nc EOF instead of waiting for more data.

Answer (score 0):

What an embarrassing oversight... :-(

`nc` quits upon reading EOF from stdin. The client which receives the data runs the LoginHook script in a non-interactive shell, which directs `nc`'s stdin descriptor probably to `/dev/null`. As soon as it reads EOF from it, it quits.

The fix is trivial: supply `-d` switch to the receiving side. This prevents either version of netcat (BSD or Linux) from reading stdin, and the transfrer completes without issue.